# Are there any frameworks smilar to hadoop yarn

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

I was wondering, wasnt there any other framework which already exist like Hadoop Yarn for managing the cluster applications and resoursing?

I felt YARN solves a general problem and I was looking out why there wasnt any other framework which tried doing this already.

I have googled but didn't find such  which is similar to Hadoop Yarn.
Is there any thing similar to YARN?

Comment: Do you mean managing Hadoop resources?  Or any distributed / cluster computing resources?

Comment: I mean any generic framework which is used for managing distributed resources and applications

Answer (score 3):

There are many resource provisioning and scheduling programs.  To name a few, there is [HTCondor](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/), [SLURM](http://slurm.schedmd.com/), [PBS](http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/products/open-source/torque/), [LSF](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/technicalcomputing/platformcomputing/products/lsf/), [SGE](http://www.univa.com/products/grid-engine) (or variants).  Each one takes a job, or multiple jobs, and schedules them on a distributed set of worker nodes.  Each has their strengths and weaknesses.  Some are free, such as HTCondor, Slurm, and torque.  Some cost, such as LSF and SGE (though free versions exist, for SGE).  It all depends on your needs.

FWIW, the original Google [paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en/us/archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf) that inspired Hadoop cited HTCondor, so you may be interested trying it out.